# Difference in precision between AVG function and sum-divide

Tags: sql-server

Similar questions have been asked before, but none have addressed why the `AVG` function in MSSQL produces a value different from explicit `SUM`and-divide when no `NULL` values are present in the data.

I would like to calculate the score for the data in this (simplified) `TestTable`.

```
CorrectCount IncorrectCount
5.0          0.0
3.0          2.0
5.0          0.0
4.0          0.0
3.0          0.0
5.0          0.0
2.0          1.0
5.0          0.0
5.0          0.0
2.0          2.0
```

The score is calculated as `score = sum(CorrectCount) / sum(CorrectCount+IncorrectCount)`

The following query

```
SELECT
  AVG(CorrectCount / (CorrectCount+IncorrectCount)) as ScoreAverage,
  SUM(CorrectCount) / SUM(CorrectCount+IncorrectCount) as ScoreSumDivide
FROM TestTable
```

produces this output:

```
ScoreAverage      ScoreSumDivide
0.876666666666667 0.886363636363636
```

Where does this difference come from? What does `AVG` do different than the `SUM`and-divide? I am looking for an explanation why the result of the AVG is different from the explicit `SUM(CorrectCount) / SUM(CorrectCount+IncorrectCount)`. I expect it is due to precision or rounding internal to the `AVG` function.

Comment: Can you please add more info on what is your exact ask ?

Comment: In one of them the operation is "sum of values" / count. In the other sum of values / sum of values. Try SUM(CorrectCount / (CorrectCount+IncorrectCount)) / Count(*) which correspond to avg..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply how the math works out. Your score average takes an average of the individual percentages.  If C1, C2 … Cn is your correct scores and I1, I2 … In is your incorrect scores and “N” is the number of records then the math will look as follow:

```
    C1/(C1+ I1) + C2 /(C2 + I2) + ... + Cn /(Cn + In)
    -------------------------------------------------
                           N
```

Your sum average first sum all of your correct scores and sum all your total scores and then calculate the percentage ratio. The math of this look as follow:

```
                C1 + C2 + ... + Cn
    ----------------------------------------------
    (C1+ I1) + (C2 + I2) + ... + (Cn + In)
```

Both numbers are meaningful but the second will better reflect what the percentage of correct counts where for the entire data set.

Answer (score 3):

Probably my comment was not understood, so I am expanding it here. Assume you have Correct/Incorrect counts as:

5/2
3/1

Averaging Correct/(Correct+Incorrect) means (5/7 + 3/4)/2 = 41/56
However Sum( Correct) /sum(Correct+Incorrect) means ( 5+3 )/(7+4)  = 8/11

41/56 != 8/11

If you did : Sum(Correct /(Correct+Incorrect))/Count it would be: (5/7 + 3/4)/2 = 41/56 which is equal to avg.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are simply calculating different stuff there. The aquivalent for the AVG should be SUM(CorrectCount / (CorrectCount + IncorrectCount)) / COUNT(*).

```
SELECT
    AVG(CorrectCount / (CorrectCount+IncorrectCount)) as ScoreAverage,
    SUM(CorrectCount / (CorrectCount + IncorrectCount)) / COUNT(*) ScoreSumDivide
```

Answer (score 1):

Your average calculation wants modification;

```
  ,AVG(CorrectCount) / (AVG(CorrectCount)+AVG(IncorrectCount)) as ScoreAverage
```

This returns the correct value of 0.886363 (39 / 44) rather than what looks like a rounding issue without it.